# jQuery animation stopping in an incomplete state on Mac using Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome, animation

I've got a strange problem that's being reported when using a site I'm working on. There's a jQuery animation that appears to "stop" in an incomplete state. The site is [www.snopsize.com](http://www.snopsize.com) and the problem occurs when you hit the big yellow carat next/back icons. Ideally, the next item should animate into view in the list.

This works on every device I have access to (a bunch of PCs running Chrome, Safari, IE, and Firefox), but I'm hearing reports that the animation just hangs halfway through and the views end up sitting stuck halfway between the next and the previous, and trying to move through the list just keeps animating to strange halfway points.

The code driving the animation is really simple:

```
$("#snop_container").stop(true, true).animate({left: '-=' + snop_width});
```

and

```
$("#snop_container").stop(true, true).animate({left: '+=' + snop_width});
```

for next and back. The snop_width is set to 775px and never changes. I'm really perplexed that this seems to work on everything I have access to but seems to fail occasionally given a certain Mac setup. I have no idea what could be happening, but any advice whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be working now in my Mac/Chrome - did you find a fix?

Comment: Nope -- I think we ended up changing the way the animation worked somehow. Perhaps switching from relative changes (shown here) to absolute? Could never quite get this working properly.